# Python Queuing integer division error

Tags: python

```
import math
import random

m = 1.5 #mu
l = 2 #lambda
c = 3 #control/number of servers

def single(m, l, c):
    p = (l/m)
    Po = (1-(l/m))
    Ls = (l/(m-l))
    Ws = (1/(m-l))
    Wq = (l/(m*(m-l)))
    Lq = (l**2/(m*(m-l)))
    return(p, Po, Ls, Ws, Wq, Lq)

def multi(m, lm, mu):
    rho=lm/mu
    n=0
    sm=0
    while(n<=m-1):
            sm=(1/math.factorial(n))*pow(rho,n)

            n+=1

    sm = sm + 1/(1/math.factorial(m))*(pow(rho,m)*m*mu/(m*mu-lm))
    lS=lm*mu*pow(rho,m)/((math.factorial(m-1)*(m*mu-lm)**2))*(1/sm)+rho
    lQ=lS-rho
    #Po = 1/sm
    return(lq, ls)

singReturn=single(m, l, c)
multiReturn=multi(3, 2, 1.5)

print("SINGLE SERVER QUEUEING")
print("-----------------------")
print("p: %4.4f \nPo: %4.4f \nLs: %4.4f \nWs: %4.4f \nWq: %4.4f \nLq: %4.4f"%singReturn)
```

I am being returned and error with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/schnipdip/Desktop/final_part1_chris_herzog.py", line 35, in <module>
    multiReturn=multi(3, 2, 1.5)
  File "/home/_____/Desktop/final_part1_.py", line 28, in multi
    sm = sm + 1/(1/math.factorial(m))*(pow(rho,m)*m*mu/(m*mu-lm))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I am trying to find the value of SM and then convert it into the Po variable. The while loop is controlling how many servers there are by m(or c) - 1. 
I changed the variables in the loop to see if the variable was being overwritten in memory by a previous value and not resetting for whatever reason. I'm sure that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Debug your variables. The error is self explanatory

Comment: Also, when I run this, I get `NameError: name 'Po' is not defined`

Comment: i understand there is a variable that is so low it registers at as a 0. However, i don't know where to locate that value and how to fix it. 

in the second method, Po, should stay commented out. I'm not sure why it would be saying that is method one runs fine, it's just method two that is outputting an error I'm having trouble with.

Comment: For easy debugging, add an `import pdb` at the top and then add a `pdb.set_trace()` just before the statement giving error. Check if the variable values are same as you expect them to be using the print command (you may want to read about pdb a bit).

Comment: Your code runs successfully in Python3 (after you fix the variables)... In python2, `(1/math.factorial(m))*(pow(rho,m)*m*mu/(m*mu-lm))` is returned as zero

Comment: If Po should stay commented out, the you can't return it on the next line. It isn't defined. Neither is `lq, ls`

Comment: Ahh yes sir, you are correct. The Po variable was still being returned. I missed that. Thank you for catching that :) You're right too, it is also the version of python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Python 2, it's probably due to this part:

```
... 1/(1/math.factorial(m)) ...
```

Logically, it doesn't make much sense:  mathematically, `1/(1/x)` is just a clumsy way to spell plain `x`.  So I bet your code has a logical error there.

But, in Python 2, it also has a programming error:  `/` applied to integers does truncating integer division in Python 2:

```
>>> import math
>>> m = 3
>>> math.factorial(m)
6
>>> 1 / math.factorial(m)
0
```

To prevent that, use, e.g., `1.0` instead of `1` to force float division:

```
>>> 1.0 / math.factorial(m)
0.16666666666666666
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you sir for your answer :) I will mark this as the correct answer to this problem. Looks like I need to update Python...

Comment: In Python 3, `/` does float division (and `//` does truncating division).  BTW, please break the habit of using `l` (lowercase L) as a variable name.  It's almost impossible to distinguish from the integer 1 in many fonts.  I had to paste your code into a text editor and convert it to uppercase to be sure you really were using the integer 1 ;-)

Comment: I wanted too, but unfortunately `l` is representative of lambda and L is going to be represented by the number of units in the queue. I should just make it lb or something. that doesn't really fix the problem.